# HTML Height changes when scrolling - space above page content is generated

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox, scroll

i've got a very strange issue with one of our webpages, when you scroll on the page there seems to be some space generated above the page which changes the height of the html container and makes the page jump around while scrolling.

As soon as I open the Inspector the issue disappears and is very hard to reproduce while the inspector is open. The issue appears in various browsers sporadically. Firefox (88.0.1, MacOS 11.4) seems to be the browser where I can reproduce it the best but it also happens on Windows 10.

I tried to capture it with quicktime the best I can (please ignore the zoom, i was holding cmd for a short moment while scrolling):
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hFNol4eAeYA

The URL of the page is: https://karlaugust.de/

Anyone has an idea where the origin of this problem could be?

Thank you!

Comment: The 'jumpiness' is the least of the problems I experience in Firefox. The bigger problem is large unrendered sections when scrolling back up from the bottom. Laggy intersection observer? You have a lot of moving parts, you'll need to try to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which may also help you isolate some of the dynamics at play.

Comment: Its very hard to find the root cause of issue i am able to replicate it on Firefox, tracing which element is doing this is difficult for the reason you have mention, i tried to narrow it down by removing section in debug but that is not helpful... rest all looks good, I noticed that issue only starts to happen when i scroll down height keeps increases with time.. something to do with scrolling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your replys, i finally pinpointed the problem:

The header (navigationbar w/ Logo, Menu etc.) was position:sticky, which seems to produce this problem when the parent container (#container) does not have a declared height (e.g. is display:block), putting the #container to display:inline-block seems to solve it. Still don't know why exactly but there seems to be a lot of bugs reported in regards to position:sticky and firefox.